# Image recognition on led lights in dashboard and Augmented reality

Tags: android, computer-vision, augmented-reality, image-recognition, android-augmented-reality

I want to recognise an image and also to extract information from the image. Like while pointing the camera on vehicle dashboard it should detect all the led lights and should show an Augmented reality information for each led lights and what is the meaning if the led is blinking.

I tried with [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/), [Craft AR](https://catchoom.com/product/craftar/augmented-reality-and-image-recognition/) and other libraries that they are focusing on recognising one single image.

For me I want to recognise an image and within that image I want to detect all the led lights and display information in augmented reality way on the camera display.

Comment: this is not a question. you cannot expect an answer. please improve your post to make it a question meeting the requirements you find here: [ask]  and what is this good for? you'll need this once or twice in 10 years. just referring to the cars manual or searching the web would be much faster than setting up some app on your smartphone when you need that knowledge, which any decent driver should have anyway about his car

Comment: This is not actual requirement.. I just gave a scenario...

Comment: yeah maybe. but it's still not a question though you might as well delete it if you are not willing to change that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for a computer vision segmentation/detecion problem. For that I would suggest to use openCV to process the images and detect the information of the leds that you need. Depending on what you want to do with that then you could need some of those AR libraries or not, but without more information I would suggest you to try to do some experiments on openCV to achieve your goals.